# How to sove the error 'The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe error'?

Tags: github

While pushing the file to github I get the above mentioned error. In detail the error is as follows:

```
Connection reset by 13.234.176.102 port 22
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: failed to push some refs to 'Github URL'
```

Is it File size issue or its corrupted?

Answer (score 5):

I met the same error today,

[image]

I google this issue and find below comments:

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/

```
If you attempt to add or update a file that is larger than 50 MB, you will receive a warning from Git. The changes will still successfully push to your repository, but you can consider removing the commit to minimize performance impact.
```

so I used the following command to resize the buffer size, it works

`git config http.postBuffer 52428800`

[image]

Comment: Did not help. Seems this is not the issue since my last commit was 3 source files with each less than 100kB.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason that I cannot explain, this error happens when the repo was cloned by git@ URL (SSH) but must be cloned by http@.. URL instead.

To FIX the error, you must change the remote origin in the local repo git config by the http@...

1.- Search and copy the http@... clone link instead git@... link.

[image]

2.- Open in your local repo folder "/.git/config" in your favorite text editor.

3.- Locate "remote ["origin"]" in the file opened.

4.- Replace the url git@... with the http@... url copied in the first step.

5.- Save the config file.

6.- Try to push your changes again.

I hope explained myself.

Good luck!